# Inspect plugin setting in current neovim session

Tags: lua, neovim, neovim-plugin

To start with, I am not well versed with `lua`, ended up learning the basics for `neovim`.

I am using pre-packaged neovim config **LazyVim** as the base for my config. I keep running into the issues, like not able to observe any visual modification w/o any errors., when I want to make some simple modification to new/existing packages.

I want to know,

1. how can i debug the plugin settings in a neovim session ?
2. Is there is a plugin that can print / allow inspecting the loaded `package` option in current session ?